(Group-)Homomorphism and subgroups
In a proof I read the following reasoning:

Given abelian Group G, subgroup <a> generated by a $\in$ G and group-homomorphism $\pi : G \to G/<a>$ (with G/<a> the quotient-group), it follows via isomorphism-theorem $|G| = |Ker(\pi)| * |G/<a>|$. Then a subgroup $H_2$ in G/<a> is given and followed that for $H_1 :=\pi^{-1}(H_2) $,  $|H_1| = |Ker(\pi)| * |H_2|$.

Im having trouble understanding why $|H_1| = |Ker(\pi)| * |H_2|$ is true, I could imagine an induced homomorphism $\pi_H: H_1 \to H_2$ but how does $|Ker(\pi)|$ come into play?

$\pi$ is $\mid\rm ker\pi\mid$ to one.  That's the preimage of each element has order $\mid\rm ker\pi\mid. $   All homomorphisms are like this.

First two remarks:

If $H_2$ is only a subset (not a subgroup as you corrected just after reading this answer), there is no "induced homomorphism $\pi_H: H_1 \to H_2$".
It is useless to assume that $G$ is abelian and that the subgroup by which we quotient it is cyclic.

More generally, let $G$ be a group, $H$ a (non necessarily normal) subgroup, $G/H$ the set of left cosets, $\pi$ the canonical surjection $G\to G/H,\;g\mapsto gH$, and $A$ a subset of $G/H$. Then,
$$|\pi^{-1}(A)|=\left|\bigcup_{a\in A}\pi^{-1}(\{a\})\right|=\sum_{a\in A}|\pi^{-1}(\{a\})|$$
and
$$\forall g\in G\quad|\pi^{-1}(\{gH\})|=|\{gh\mid h\in H\}|=|H|$$
hence
$$|\pi^{-1}(A)|=\sum_{a\in A}|H|=|A||H|.$$
(When the subgroup $H$ is normal, $G/H$ is a group, $\pi$ is a homomorphism, and $H$ is its kernel.)
This is the shepherds' principle: $n$ sheep have $4n$ feet.

I see no reason for a downvote (+1).
